# Java servlet can't handle get and post requests simultaneously

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, concurrency

So I thought that the servlet I made could handle requests through GET and POST at the same time (concurrently) when my webpage is communicating with the server. It might be that since it is the same page making both requests there is only one thread handling both requests. What's happening is I have a POST request getting called through a JQuery AJAX request and on success of the request it calls a callback javascript method that has a JQuery AJAX GET request. My understanding might possibly be wrong on what constitutes a successful request. Any suggestions or explanations on how I can get this to work or why it won't work would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you confirm the requests weren't being handled simultaneously? At any rate, any "simultaneous" effect you've ever observed is mostly simulated: except on a multicore machine - all threads are processed round-robin (with slight variations platform to platform)

Comment: I'd add logging when the get/post handler is entered and left and add some artificial sleep between entering and leaving a handler to confirm that this is actually the case.

Comment: @kolossus I don't need them to necessarily be simultaneous but my POST method seems to block until it's done. I'll try to add more context to my question to make the problem more clear.

Comment: Are your doGet() and doPost() method synchronised against each other.

Comment: @EJP I'm not sure what you mean by your question.

Comment: I don't quite understand. It seems like you make one request, then that request calls a method in the WebServlet class?

Comment: @CodeEnthusiast your question is still a bit dark here mate. If you request the POST and then the GET, it's only fair the POST completes before the GET no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your case using glassfish4, servlet-api 3 and I observed following:

First I created a servlet that serves both get and post. This servlet had a 5 second thread sleep delay

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloServlet.class);

  public HelloServlet() {
    super();
    logger.debug("HelloServlet created");
  }

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.debug("get start");
    try { Thread.sleep(5000); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    logger.debug("get finish");
    super.doGet(req, resp);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    logger.debug("post start");
    try { Thread.sleep(5000); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    logger.debug("post finish");
    super.doPost(req, resp);
  }

}
```

I then tried invoking both GET and POST within 5 seconds window and this is what it looks like

```
INFO: 2013-07-07 14:06:06 DEBUG HelloServlet:21 - HelloServlet created
INFO: 2013-07-07 14:06:06 DEBUG HelloServlet:27 - get start
INFO: 2013-07-07 14:06:08 DEBUG HelloServlet:41 - post start
INFO: 2013-07-07 14:06:11 DEBUG HelloServlet:34 - get finish
INFO: 2013-07-07 14:06:13 DEBUG HelloServlet:48 - post finish
```

- Only 1 instance of HelloServlet is created, this seem to be shared by
  all http worker threads
- Both get and post requests are served by different threads and invocation of get and post method are not synchronized

So your original understanding seem right